# Designing an app with lots of information, including links to different parts of a page

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am wanting to design an app that contains a lot of information and I want to separate the information into sections that can be flicked to. See the image below for exactly what I want to do:

[Skyscape Medical Resources App http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/103/Purple/v4/34/6d/1e/346d1e3d-ad60-1197-ee65-de8b7ed00f84/mzl.nrrlmqlx.480x480-75.jpg](http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/103/Purple/v4/34/6d/1e/346d1e3d-ad60-1197-ee65-de8b7ed00f84/mzl.nrrlmqlx.480x480-75.jpg)

How can I design something like this? I cant figure out what kind of view that has been used. I see elements of a tableview (the grey horizontal lines) but then I see different fonts and colours in a tablecell (if it is a tableview).
There are also links at the top which flick down to the section in below that corresponds to it. They also have the links as blue underlined text, how do you do that?

So in essence, 2 questions:

1) How have they likely designed the Master view of the picture shown? (Is it a tableview, or just one big viewcontroller. If its a tableview, how do you get different font styles in a text cell like they have)
2) How do you create those blue text links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looked around and found that the likely design is a UIWebView as it can incorporate hyperlinks, and different fonts.